# What type of encoding/encryption has been used?

Tags: encryption

Encrypted output:

```
mgmt_opq=kdS+yok8yWM=:zS0U62VvOPI=:6C9zqH5bnu4=
```

Read all related posts, tried with Base64 decoders but didn't work.

### Additional info

The output should be an Ethernet MAC address: 6 bytes, 48bits.

```
# fw_printenv | grep opq
mgmt_opq=kdS+yok8yWM=:zS0U62VvOPI=:6C9zqH5bnu4=
```

`kdS+yok8yWM=` should be the first word(16 bit) of  MAC address

`zS0U62VvOPI=` should be second word of MAC address

`6C9zqH5bnu4=` should be third word of MAC address

Comment: Where did you get this string from?  Knowing that would probably help.

Comment: is the output of a MAC address 48 bits, 6 bytes. 16bits:16bits:16bits  i guess

Comment: # fw_printenv | grep opq
mgmt_opq=kdS+yok8yWM=:zS0U62VvOPI=:6C9zqH5bnu4=

Comment: # cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 1 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 1192.75
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp
CPU implementer : 0x56
CPU architecture: 5TE
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0x131
CPU revision    : 1
Cache type      : write-back
Cache clean     : cp15 c7 ops
Cache lockdown  : format C
Cache format    : Harvard
I size          : 16384
I assoc         : 4
I line length   : 32
I sets          : 128
D size          : 16384
D assoc         : 4
D line length   : 32
D sets          : 128

Comment: # cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.22.18 (gcc version 4.2.0 20070413 (prerelease)) #1 Sun Aug 7 07:41:37 IDT 2016

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea Is the answer below not enough or why are you still extending the question? (Oh, now it's gone...)

Answer (score 2):

Your output contains three colon-separated strings which *are* valid base64 sequences.

You shouldn't assume that base64-decoded data is always in the printable ASCII range since you can encode arbitrary binary. Here is the output:

```
kdS+yok8yWM=
00000000: 91d4 beca 893c c963                      .....<.c

zS0U62VvOPI=
00000000: cd2d 14eb 656f 38f2                      .-..eo8.

6C9zqH5bnu4=
00000000: e82f 73a8 7e5b 9eee                      ./s.~[..
```

That doesn't match the format of a single MAC address (48 bit) because each of the three segments has a length of 8 bytes (64 bit).

Comment: kdS+yok8yWM=
00000000: 91d4 beca 893c c963                      .....<.c

zS0U62VvOPI=
00000000: cd2d 14eb 656f 38f2                      .-..eo8.

6C9zqH5bnu4=
00000000: e82f 73a8 7e5b 9eee                      ./s.~[..    But this doesnt make sense, right ? tried with Base64 saw the same thing, but the output should be a MAC address.  16bit:16bit:16bit

Comment: why "-2" votes ? dumb question or what?

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea You question was downvoted because you didn't provide any context and "what is that encryption?" questions are generally discouraged.

Comment: I see. Sorry for that. I do research a lot before i ask.

Comment: Any other thoughts other than Base64 ?

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea I still think it's base64. That's consistent with the character range and the padding (`=`) at the end.

Comment: Strange output. Should be a MAC address but like you said every segment has 8 bytes. hmm...

Comment: now its "-3" :)

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea If you have found a solution you can post it as an answer. :)

Comment: I asked the device's vendor to provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It was that `mgmt_opq=kdS+yok8yWM=:zS0U62VvOPI=:6C9zqH5bnu4=` it is a key (opaque format) used by the vendor to register the specified device to a server database.

Opaque data type:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type

Comment: So it was no MAC address after all, like you said before Sigh. And I don't get what part about a key/serial is an unknown format. Raw encryption keys or pseudorandom serial data are not supposed to have some human-readable format.

Comment: @deviantfan Youre right. They call this key "Opaque MAC".